# Why "Watchman crawl failed" error in react-native immediately after updating to macOS catalina?

Tags: terminal, react-native, react-native-ios, watchman

Trying to run `react-native run-ios` or build RN project from xcode, as soon as metro bundler starts, this error appears in the terminal:

```
Loading dependency graph...jest-haste-map: Watchman crawl failed. Retrying once with node crawler.
  Usually this happens when watchman isn't running. Create an empty `.watchmanconfig` file in your project's root folder or initialize a git or hg repository in your project.
  Error: Watchman error: resolve_projpath: path `/Users/vorousjames/Desktop/Development/TicTacWHOA/app/TicTacWHOA`: open: /Users/vorousjames/Desktop/Development/TicTacWHOA/app/TicTacWHOA: Operation not permitted. Make sure watchman is running for this project. See https://facebook.github.io/watchman/docs/troubleshooting.html.
events.js:183
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
  ^

Error: resolve_projpath: path `/Users/vorousjames/Desktop/Development/TicTacWHOA/app/TicTacWHOA`: open: /Users/vorousjames/Desktop/Development/TicTacWHOA/app/TicTacWHOA: Operation not permitted
    at BunserBuf.<anonymous> (/Users/vorousjames/Desktop/Development/TicTacWHOA/app/TicTacWHOA/node_modules/fb-watchman/index.js:95:23)
    at emitOne (events.js:116:13)
    at BunserBuf.emit (events.js:211:7)
    at BunserBuf.process (/Users/vorousjames/Desktop/Development/TicTacWHOA/app/TicTacWHOA/node_modules/bser/index.js:292:10)
    at /Users/vorousjames/Desktop/Development/TicTacWHOA/app/TicTacWHOA/node_modules/bser/index.js:247:12
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:131:7)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:180:9)
```

This never happened before the Catalina update. I've had an empty watchman config file in the root of my project since the beginning. On first boot post-update, there was a popup in terminal saying something about permissions but i dont remember exactly. there's also a notice in my terminal in visual studio code saying "the default shell changed to zsh" run `chsh -s /bin/zsh` to change, so i did.

I've tried:

- `watchman watch-del-all`
- `watchman server-shutdown`
- adding full disk access to terminal from within system preferences->privacy tab
- `npm uninstall watchman` & `npm uninstall -g watchman`

Comment: [Moved this to an answer, even though it's more of a troubleshooting thing]

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I had the same issue after updating to Catalina.  Wez Furlong's answer worked for me, but I had to provide full disk access to watchman in order to run watchman watch-project command without getting "Operation not permitted" error.  As part of prior troubleshooting, I also had provided full disk access to Xcode and Terminal (not sure if this also contributed to the fix).

[image]

Comment: ultimately i never had the .plist file Wez Furlong suggested to remove, i reinstalled watchman, gave full disk access to one of like 13 watchman programs, ran `watchman watch-project` as suggested here and everything worked. thanks so much

Comment: Where is your project located?(~ or somewhere else inside ~)

Comment: This is the correct answer. Helped me fix the issues after Catalina upgrade.

System Preferences -> Security & Privacy -> Privacy -> Full Disk Access -> Enable watchman

Comment: What to do if watchman isn't in that list of apps?

Comment: @CallumThomas I am facing the same issue, I cannot see watchman in the list of apps even after installing it using brew. How did you fix the issue?

Comment: @ZahirMasoodi It must be hidden in the homebrew cellar directory.
After clicking on the plus icon in Full Disk Access, select Macintosh HD folder, press command+shift+. (period) and you will see hidden folders. From there, go to opt > homebrew > Cellar > watchman > 2023.01.16.00 (Folder name based on watchman installation date) > bin and select the watchman.
Hope this helps!

Answer (score 38):

You need to grant disk access to `watchman`. To do this You need to:

- Go to `System preferences` > `Security & Privacy` then scroll down
- Select `Full Disk Access`
- Unlock it and click `+` button to add new app/tool
- Select `Macintosh HD` in the folders list
- Press this combination `shift` `Command` `.` at the same time to see all the directories list
- Click `opt > brew > bin` (watchman is installed in this folder for MacOS Catalina) || `usr > local > Cellar > Watchman > 21***** > bin` (watchman is installed in this folder MacOS Monterey)
- Look for `watchman` in the list then select it

Here we go, this should fix the issue.

Comment: I had the same problem after upgrading to Mac OS Monterey and this solved it for me except my watchman is located in usr/local/Cellar

Comment: Worked perfectly, thank you!

Comment: Unfortunately this didn't work for me. And watchman already had Files & Folders permission.

Comment: So it seems v2022.05.30.00 is broken. See: [here](https://github.com/facebook/watchman/issues/1030)

Comment: It may be necessary to restart the watchman service (`watchman shutdown-server` then `watchman`) after doing these steps for them to take effect. Also consider clearing its cache with `watchman watch-del-all` or opening a new terminal window if that doesn't work.

Comment: When still doesn't work try to restart your device

Comment: I had two different listings of `watchman` there, I enabled both, enabled `iTerm` too then restarted it, then it worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 32):

First run `watchman watch-del-all`
then run `watchman shutdown-server` fixed my issue

Answer (score 15):

To change the permissions for Watchman regarding the Documents folder, it's under Security & Privacy -> files & folders in the system preferences

My issue was resolved by checking Watchman in the list under Document folder

Answer (score 2):

The error message indicates a permission problem on `/Users/vorousjames/Desktop/Development/TicTacWHOA/app/TicTacWHOA`.

However, it may be something funky with launchd, so I would suggest:

```
$ watchman shutdown-server
$ launchctl unload ~/Library/LaunchAgents/com.github.facebook.watchman.plist
$ rm ~/Library/LaunchAgents/com.github.facebook.watchman.plist
$ watchman watch-project /Users/vorousjames/Desktop/Development/TicTacWHOA/app/TicTacWHOA
```

and see if that works or shows more context.

Cross linking back to an issue in our GitHub tracker:
https://github.com/facebook/watchman/issues/751

Comment: result: `Jamess-MacBook-Pro:TicTacWHOA vorousjames$ watchman watch-project /Users/vorousjames/Desktop/Development/TicTacWHOA/app/TicTacWHOA
{
    "version": "4.9.0",
    "error": "resolve_projpath: path `/Users/vorousjames/Desktop/Development/TicTacWHOA/app/TicTacWHOA`: open: /Users/vorousjames/Desktop/Development/TicTacWHOA/app/TicTacWHOA: Operation not permitted"}`

Answer (score 2):

You need to change something its works for me. follow only following steps:

```
1. Go to System preferences > Security & Privacy then scroll down.
2. Select    Full Disk Access.
3. Look for all watchmen on the list.
4. check(Mark) all Folders in all watchman files. 
5. then go to vs code.
6. rebuilt your code.
I hope it will work smoothly
```

Comment: checking all watchman files on the list solved my problem, thanks

Comment: i had to restart my mac before rebuilt to get worked.

Answer (score 1):

It is related that `Documents` or another folder permission is privacy.
Try to `sudo` to access terminal as below.

0. `brew reinstall watchman` (optional)
1. `sudo npx react-native start`terminal.
2. Apply watchman permission popup.
3. Done

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the directory of your project. I had mine on desktop and was getting that error, moved to the home folder and the error is gone

Answer (score 0):

Just uncheck the repeated boxes in Mac:

System Preferences -> Security and privacy -> Privacy

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For me above scenario didn't work, so I tried with different solution which solved the problem for me. (I am using MacBook Pro, chip: Apple M1 pro)

At first you have to update the setting of your Mac OS

System Preference  >> security & privacy >> privacy tab >> Full disk access >> click on the lock icon >> checkmark for terminal

Sometime using this steps you are able to resolve the issue, but after this, if you are still facing issue, please use this link: [#1030 (comment)](https://github.com/facebook/watchman/issues/1030#issuecomment-1145766948)

Answer (score 0):

on macos. `brew uninstall watchman`
it works for me

Comment: Please read [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). While this code block may answer the OP's question, this answer would be much more useful if you explain how this code is different from the code in the question, what you've changed, why you've changed it and why that solves the problem without introducing others.

Answer (score -1):

npx react-native start --port=8088  resolved mine

Answer (score -1):

There is only one solution at the moment. Move your project from the "Desktop" or "Documents" folder to the main folder (~/). None of the other ways worked for me.

This is because MacOS now asks for permissions for these folders (example in the image below). I guess this hasn't been added to the watchman yet.

[image: Example permission]

Answer (score -1):

As a temporary workaround, you can move your project to your home folder and it should run successfully.

To open your home folder, press Command-Shift-H.

(As of June 2022, there seems to be an issue with the 2022.05.30.00 version of Watchman, and this temporary solution is the only way I have been able to get around the issue.)