# Watchman won't let me start any of my react native projects after i updated my mac OS

Tags: reactjs, react-native, watchman

This is my first time asking a question so please bear with me if i’m not asking according to the standards but ill try my best.

watchman warning: opendir(/Users/abdi/Library/VoiceTrigger/SAT) -> Operation not permitted. Marking this portion of the tree deleted
To clear this warning, run:
`watchman watch-del /Users/abdi ; watchman watch-project /Users/abdi`

This is the error i'm getting every time i try start any project, even the ones that i created previously.

I tried the following:

1. `watchman watch-del /Users/abdi ; watchman watch-project /Users/abdi`
2. Giving watchman full-disk access and restarting
3. Moving my project to root folder (/Users/abdi)

This is what i get when i run watchman watch-list
{
    "version": "4.9.0",
    "roots": [
        "/Users/abdi"
    ]
}

Please help.

Answer (score 18):

Bit late to the party, but to me the following worked

1. Shut down the metro server / simulator (if it's running)
2. Turn off and clear watchman cache

   ```bash
   $ watchman shutdown-server
   $ watchman watch-del-all
   ```
3. Start your [react-native](/questions/tagged/react-native) project (i.e. `react-native start`, `expo start`, etc.)

There's no need to give watchman full disk access *(nor should you)*

Comment: It works, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

﻿You need to grant full disk access to watchman to allow it to watch the locations you've asked it to watch.

Go to 'System preferences' -> 'Security & Privacy' -> scroll down and click 'Full Disk Access', and then check 'Watchman'.

After changing this, restart your laptop.

See these other links for more information:

- https://github.com/facebook/watchman/issues/751
- [Why "Watchman crawl failed" error in react-native immediately after updating to macOS catalina?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58318341/why-watchman-crawl-failed-error-in-react-native-immediately-after-updating-to)

Comment: Thanks for your answer Wez. Unfortunately that doesn't work for me. I have also tried everything suggested in those discussions but still have the problem.

Comment: Nothing works, hooray!

Answer (score 0):

I found solution. After giving full disk access use `watchman watch /Users/$USER/....` to watch your project instead of `watchman watch-project /Users/$USER/....`

Comment: Thank you for the tips, I ran `watchman watch .` at my project's directory and it solved the problem.