# Can't use Watchman: "Operation not permitted"

Tags: watchman

Since updating Watchman recently (with Homebrew) I can no longer use it to watch projects. I get

```json
{
    "version": "2022.05.30.00",
    "error": "std::__1::system_error: open: /Users/Path/To/Project: Operation not permitted"
}
```

I initially assumed that this must simply be file access issue I could [resolve in the normal way](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58327671/656912), but giving the watchman app access to Files & Folders does not resolve the issue (even with termination of all watchman processes and restart of Terminal).

For good measure, I also [manually added the watchman executable to Full Disk Access](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68962390/656912) (something I've never needed to do before and am not comfortable with) but this also had no effect.

I have also terminated every relevant process I can think of, and even rebooted, twice. As far as I know the *only* change since Watchman worked was my running `brew update watchman` (which I have of course also uninstalled and reinstalled).

One concern is that for some reason I have multiple entries for watchmen in System Preferences, which weirdly results in it taking several dozen attempts to whack-a-mole all of them into a checked state for access:

[image]

How do I give Watchman the permissions needs to overcome this error?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

## Update Aug-19-2022

It looks like `watchman: stable 2022.08.15.00` is working fine on my Mac M1. Upon start, you need to grant access to the local folders about to be synched.

---

## Original

I also had the problem, like many others.

I reverted to a "working" version, e.g. 2022.05.16.00

There are multiple ways to do so; one (without private taps) would be:

1. Uninstall watchman
2. Downgrade the watchman.rb formula to an older version

   - https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/find/master
   - Navigate to watchman.rb
   - History -> select needed version -> View file -> Raw
   - Copy link to raw data
   - replace formula with that from raw version link
3. Install watchman according to that version
4. Pin it (to prevent further watchman updates)
5. Finally reset the watchman.rb formula to the original state again

```
# -- 1 -- uninstall
brew uninstall watchman
# -- 2 -- replace formula
curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/8651d8e23d308e564414188509f864e40548f514/Formula/watchman.rb > /opt/homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-core/Formula/watchman.rb
# -- 3 -- install again, using replaced formula
brew install watchman
# -- 4 -- pin that version - Don't forget to unpin once this problem is solved...
brew pin watchman 
# -- 5 -- reset formula to original
cd /opt/homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-core/Formula/
git checkout -- watchman.rb
```

Then shutdown any lingering instances of Watchman with

```
watchman shutdown-server
```

**Remark**: On Intel-Macs, homebrews repository is located at a different place. You can find out by calling `brew --repository`.
Typically, the Formula is expected in directory `/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-core/Formula`

Once the problems with watchman are solved, you can unpin watchman again and use the normal brew update/upgrade machanism.

Comment: I get:
```text
/opt/homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-core/Formula/watchman.rb: No such file or directory
```
I don't even have an `/opt/homebrew/`, just an `/opt/homebrew-cask/`, which is empty.

Comment: Should I be using `/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-core/Formula/watchman.rb` instead?

Comment: @orome Yes, for Intel-Macs, it's located in /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-core/Formula

Comment: For me `git checkout` gives: `fatal: not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git` (using `/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-core/Formula/watchman.rb`).

Comment: That's strange. On my Intel mac:
`$git status /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-core/Formula
On branch master
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/master'.`

Comment: I guess that's [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72492307/656912) then.

Comment: A small mistake of mine: command should be `git -C <PATH> status`, thanks to @torek

Comment: OK, `staus` works now but I still get an error with `it checkout -- /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-core/Formula/watchman.rb`: `fatal: not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git`. Should I have other flags there too, or be in a particular location when I execute?

Comment: @orome Same problem as with `git status` - you need to cd into that directory and then call `git checkout watchman.rb` I'm not sure why git behaves this way, but it seems to be the way it's working. I'll update my answer.

Comment: Yeah what threw me off was `-C` wasn’t working. All set now. Thanks!

Comment: I've run `git checkout watchman.rb` but it returns "Updated 0 paths from the index". What happens now?

Comment: Best answer, I've been finding the solution for so long. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks, it works for me. To unpin: ```brew unpin watchman```

Answer (score 67):

On my M1 Mac:

My issue was that watchman didn't have permissions to `~/Documents` folder. I don't know if this was the case before or after reinstalled it. Here are the steps I took:

```
brew uninstall watchman
brew install watchman
watchman shutdown-server (just in case it's running)
watchman watch-del-all
yarn start --reset-cache
```

When I tried to launch metro, MacOS prompted me to give permissions. After accepting, the bundler ran without issue.

Comment: This is different than the original issue, which was a bug in older versions. What you describe is the normal behavior (pretty much).

Comment: @orome I answered the author's question about watchman permissions on M1. That's all that is required.

Comment: For me, it's fixed the problem. However, I didn't do the first two steps.

Comment: `watchman watch-del-all` prompt me to allow directory access. Maybe it is all we needed.

Comment: @vozaldi whatever works for you, great! The easier, the better.

Answer (score 29):

If the server and client versions don't match up, you should probably restart your server: `watchman shutdown-server ; watchman`

https://facebook.github.io/watchman/docs/cmd/version.html

Comment: this was my problem after doing a `brew upgrade`, just had to shut down a previous instance of watchman and built with no issues

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned previously, you need to 'Accept' perms for watchman again. I use yarn and needed to run 'npm start' to show dialog again.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the problem is that the watchman didn't have permission to access the ~/Documents folder.  Reinstalling watchmen seems to work as it triggers the grant access prompt.

Comment: This was a bug with an older version of `watchman` that has now been fixed.

Answer (score 0):

We can also encounter this error message when running React Native apps. To resolve the error, we need to re-request permissions for the `watchman` tool which RN uses.

Navigate to the project root folder and run `npm start` in a Terminal. This should request permissions for `watchman` and once granted, we can build the app again.

The typical build process outside a terminal doesn't re-request permissions which is why we need to start from a Terminal separately.