# Misconfigured local Homebrew formula repo?

Tags: git, homebrew

On my (Intel) mac entering

```
git status /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-core/Formula
```

I get:

```
fatal: not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
```

I'm pretty sure that's what's supposed to happen. How do I restore my Homebrew to the correct configuration?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`git status` operates on the Git repository you're in right now. If `/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-core/Formula` *is* a Git repository, you would need to run:

```
cd /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-core/Formula
git status
```

There *is* a short-cut for this, but it's not `git status /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-core/Formula` ; instead, it is:

```
git -C /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-core/Formula status
```

The `-C` flag to `git` (not to the `status` sub-command! it goes directly to the front end `git`) tells that command that it should first do a `cd` to the supplied argument, then run the sub-command *in* that directory.  Note that this will not affect your *current working directory*, i.e., when the `git status` command has finished, you are still in whichever directory you were in when you started.

(The `-C` flag to `git` generally works with all the Git sub-commands, but you need to re-specify it each time, which is why we usually just `cd` somewhere first.  Then we're *in* that directory and can do the next however-many commands without repeating the path.  In Unix-style shells, you can create a sub-shell and cd into some place and work, then exit the sub-shell to return to where you were, without having to remember where you were, but many shells—bash and zsh among them—will also maintain a "directory stack" with `pushd` and `popd` commands for you.  There's one other short-cut in many shells: `cd -` will go back to a single previous remembered path.)